# Replace all images in XML file to Base64

Tags: xml, image, base64, encode, src

I want to replace all images file with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) of them, for example, my source xml file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- some other tags -->
<img src="http://example.com/img_194.jpg" />

<img src="http://example.com/photo5.jpg" />
<!-- some other tags -->
```

and I want my target xml file become like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- some other tags -->
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, iVBORw0ljNBAAO9TXLljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwKGgoAAAAN0ljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwKGgoAAAANY4OHwKGgoAAAANiV..." />

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwKGgoAAAANJRU5ErkJggg=..." />
<!-- some other tags -->
```

Any solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution

```
perl  -MDigest::MD5 -pi -e 's/src="([^"]+)"/"src=\"data:image\/jpg;base64, " . Digest::MD5::md5_base64($1)."\""/ge' file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I want to convert **external image file** to Base64 code, not url of it.